# How to convert string type to Path type?

Tags: python, string, file, path, operating-system

I'm trying to open a video with opencv, but my file path is a variable that depends on the user's input. I noticed that even the file path being a string, when we try to concatenate two strings to became a path, python don't allow it. So I want to know how can i convert string type to Path type. I've already tried these two methodes, but it still does not work:

```
from pathlib import Path
str_path = "my_path"
path = Path(str_path)


import os    
p = "my/path/to/file.py"
os.path.normpath(p)
'my\\path\\to\\file.py'
```

These are the functions that i tried the method above

```
def show_index_tutorial(list):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        print(i,"\t",list[i])
    tutorial_choice = int(input("Digte a opcao: "))
    tutorial = list[tutorial_choice]
    return tutorial 

# retorna o path do video escolhido
def file_path(section,tutorial):
    head_111 = os.path.split(r"D:\Users\raulc\Documents\AMBIENTES\videos\111\T1_111.mp4")[0]
    head_113 = os.path.split(r"D:\Users\raulc\Documents\AMBIENTES\videos\113\T2_113.mp4")[0]
    if section == 111:
        path = os.path.join(head_111,tutorial) # tutorial e o return da funcao show_index_tutorial
    else:
        path = os.path.join(head_113,tutorial)
    return (os.path.normpath("r"+(f'"{path}"')))
```

This is where I tried to use the path:

```
p111 = os.listdir(path_111)
tutorial = show_index_tutorial(p111)
x = file_path(111,tutorial)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(x)
```

And this is the output that I got:

```
Digite o ID: 5DBEF04B
Digite o ID: 5DBEF04B
0        T1_111.mp4 
1        T2_111.ppsx
2        T3_111.mp4 
Digte a opcao: 0    
Error opening video  file
```

Comment: why do you say the second version is not ok with you? Because of the double backslash?

Comment: Why do you think this isn't working?

Comment: Your question mentions concatenating strings, but neither of your examples does that.

Comment: Sorry, the question was a little confusing, I edited it to become more clear. Can you understand now?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem, my mistake was that I was usig quotation marks `("r"+(f'"{path}"'))` on the function below:

```
def file_path(section,tutorial):
    head_111 = os.path.split(r"D:\Users\raulc\Documents\AMBIENTES\videos\111\T1_111.mp4")[0]
    head_113 = os.path.split(r"D:\Users\raulc\Documents\AMBIENTES\videos\113\T2_113.mp4")[0]
    if section == 111:
        path = os.path.join(head_111,tutorial) # tutorial e o return da funcao show_index_tutorial
    else:
        path = os.path.join(head_113,tutorial)
    return (os.path.normpath("r"+(f'"{path}"')))
```

The right way is:

```
def file_path(section,tutorial):
    head_111 = path_111
    head_113 = path_113
    if section == 111:
        path = os.path.join(head_111,tutorial) # tutorial é o return da funcao show_index_tutorial
    else:
        path = os.path.join(head_113,tutorial)
    return (os.path.normpath(path))
```

The `os.path.normpath` already makes Windows read the variable as if it was a raw string.

I hope I could help people with the same problem!